# Matlab function area() not working

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

The in-build matlab function area() stopped working.
I tried to run the example from the documentation:

```
Y = [1, 5, 3;
     3, 2, 7;
     1, 5, 3;
     2, 6, 1];
figure
area(Y)
```

but I would get the error message

```
Error using area (line 35)
Too many input arguments.
```

I am using 8.5.0.197613 (R2015a).

Comment: Works for me :). Are you absolutely sure that this is the code that you are running? Perhaps you have another function or variable named `area`? This can be checked with `which area`.

Comment: `which area gives ` me `\R2015a\toolbox\matlab\specgraph\area.m`. So I think it should be the correct one.

Comment: Sounds very strange. Can you reproduce the error after restarting your Matlab?

Comment: Yes, I restarted Matlab as well as my PC, just to be safe.

Comment: can you open area (line 35) and see what it is?

Comment: It's the beginning of the area function. Here is a snippet: 
`% First we check which HG plotting API should be used.
    if ishg2parent( varargin{:} )
        [~, cax, args] = parseplotapi(varargin{:},'-mfilename',mfilename);
        try
            h = areaHGUsingMATLABClasses(cax, args{:});
        catch me
            throw(me)
        end
    else`

Line 35 is `throw(me)`.

Comment: Run [`restoredefaultpath`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/restoredefaultpath.html) to remove all 3rd party sources from the search path. If the error still exists with the default search path, I am convinced that this is a bug in MATLAB. Contact the support.

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm ! 
On a side note, instead of `which area` I used `which -all area`, and I saw that there were two functions called `area`. However, when looking at which one was called, it turned out to be the correct one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup><sup>This CW answer was created to indicate that this question was resolved.</sup></sup>
This turned out to be an issue related to the MATLAB search path. Using [`restoredefaultpath`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/restoredefaultpath.html) resolved it.

A symptom of this problem can appear when running `which -all <function name>` (without the `<>`), and getting back a list with unexpected entries.

From [the documentation of `which`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html#outputarg_str):

> *The results are ordered according to the [Function Precedence Order](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-precedence-order.html), unless they are shadowed. Among shadowed results, you should not rely on the order of the functions and methods in `str`. To determine if a result is shadowed, call `which` without specifying an output. `which` indicates shadowed results by the comment, `% Shadowed`*.